# jQuery callback function not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I type something in the text box, nothing happens.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>POST/GET Data (HTTP Request)</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
        <div id="name_feedback"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#name').keyup(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        $.post('php/process_name.php', { "name": name }, function(data) {
            $('#name_feedback').html(data);         
        });
    });
});
```

This is PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo strrev($name);
        }
?>
```

I want to echo out the reverse string as the user types something.

Comment: whether the ajax request sent to server? check your browwer console for any error

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#name').keyup(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        $.post('php/process_name.php', { name: name }, function(data) {
            $('#name_feedback').html(data);         
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what you've changed from the OP's code and why it would fix the problem. Is the only difference in your code that you've added a document ready handler? That isn't necessary when the script element is included after the elements it references.

Comment: @nnnnnn If you went through the OP's edits, you'd see that they didn't pass the callback properly.

Comment: The edit history only shows changes to whitespace in that code block (and doesn't include any changes by the OP). So the only difference I can see in your answer is the additional of a redundant document ready handler. In any case my point is that people reading your answer shouldn't be forced to do a character-by-character comparison with the question to see what you've changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at browser itself(without php) with jquery.

```
$(function(){
    $('#name').keyup(function() {
            var name = $('#name').val();
            $('#name_feedback').html(name.split("").reverse().join(""));         
    });
});
```

Comment: If you only need to reverse the string you don't need to process it from server. You can do it in the browser itself. It will reduce server load.

Comment: Yes, you obviously _can_ get the result with just JS, but why would the OP's code not work?

Comment: Probably its because you didn't wrap your jquery code inside self executing function. I mean: $(function(){ //your code here });

Comment: Or you can try the process with your console opened and inspect for an javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use on to bind events,

```
$('#name').on('keyup',function() {
var name = $('#name').val();
$.post('php/process_name.php', { 
    name: name 
}, function(data) {
    $('#name_feedback').html(data);         
});
});
```

Comment: But the `.keyup()` method is just a shortcut that should produce the same result. Why would `.on()` fix the problem?

Comment: .on will bind dynamic events so it is better to use on. Will an alert in success function work?

Comment: `.on()` only binds events to dynamically created elements (assuming that's what you meant) when you pass it different parameters to what you've shown - your code is equivalent to `.keyup()`. And in any case the OP doesn't have dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0):

just check this

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#name').keyup(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        $.post('php/process_name.php', { "name": name }, function(data) {
            $('#name_feedback').html(data);         
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It can be done on client side but if you are willing to do it at server side then it might help you.

Comment: Quotes do not make a difference (unless, as you noted, you want to use a key that’s not a valid JavaScript identifier).

Comment: Please check php file path and mention dataType ( it is optional) in ajax post method  ... see the link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp